# Mac Keeps Messages Deleted From iPhone

Tags: icloud, macos, messages, ios

When I delete messages from my iPhone, my Macbook Air keeps copies of the messages, is there a way to enable sync so that when I delete the messages from iPhone they delete on Mac and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

No. Messages are not synced in this manner. The only sync is whether or not a particular message has been read. Once a message is delivered to a device/computer, it stays on that device/computer until it is deleted specifically from that machine.